# postgres time conversion hh:mm:ss.us to hh:mm

Tags: postgresql, datetime, time

Using PostgreSQL database for my attendance application.

I have a table with IN and out times (hh:mm:ss.us format).

When I subtract the times (OUT -IN) to calculate the working hours, results are not as expected due to precision.

If IN Time is "22:12:56.09" 
& OUT TIme is "22:14:06.06" the difference considering only HH:mm should be 00:02 but it actually shows "00:01:09.97"   which becomes "00:01" in excel using only HH:mm.

I am trying to do the time conversion from hh:mm:ss.us to hh:mm (time format) so that I can subtract the time and get the desired output.

I have done similar things in SQL Server but I did not find any function in PostgreSQL. Please advise.

Comment: What data type are those columns? A `time` column has no "format", you can _display_ them in any format you want using `to_char()`. From your description it also sounds as if you really want an `interval` which is a duration not a `time` (which represents a single point in time, **not**  a duration in minutes and seconds)

Comment: Set the "precision" with `(p)` as documented here. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

First you need to truncate the seconds. Then subtract to get desired result

select

```
to_char(
  (
    to_char('22:14:06.06' :: time, 'HH24:MI'):: time - 
    to_char('22:12:56.09' :: time, 'HH24:MI'):: time
  ),
  'HH24:MI'
)
```

*Result*: 00:02

General Solution:

```
select
  to_char(
  (
    to_char(out, 'HH24:MI'):: time - to_char(in, 'HH24:MI'):: time
  ),
  'HH24:MI'
)
```

Here the purpose of to_char() is to format result to hours:minutes and not to include seconds.
Postgres includes seconds in interval by default.

Comment: `to_char('22:14:06.06' :: time, 'HH24:MI'):: time` can be simplified to `time '22:14:06.06'`

Comment: But we need to truncate the seconds BEFORE subtracting . to_char() with format 'HH24:MI' is used to truncate seonds.
Also after subtracting , the result will be of type interval hours:minutes:seconds (i.e.00:02:00).
But we need hours:minutes (i.e.00:02).
Hence the interval (out-in) again formated using to_char() with format 'HH24:MI'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the date_trunc function with timestamp.

It would work something like this:
`select date_trunc('minute', out) - date_trunc('minute', in)`

This would set a minute level precision on the timestamp and convert HH:mm:ss to HH:mm:00